# Celery task does not appear in queue after task.apply_async using countdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I Hope this question qualifies for stack overflow.

Working with celery 4.2.0 and Redis as broker and backend.

Having a task

```
@shared_task()
def add(a, b):
    return a+b
```

And while a **worker is active**, running the fallowing command:

```
add.apply_async(countdown=60)
```

Results in the task not being registered to the default **celery** queue,
but still being executed after the period of time stated in **countdown**

Why is that, and how can I look for all pending tasks?
Doing this would have worked if the task would be registered to the queue:

```
    with celery_app.pool.acquire(block=True) as conn:
        tasks = conn.default_channel.client.lrange('celery', 0, -1)
```

If I terminate the worker while task havent been started I get the fallowing:

```
[WARNING/MainProcess] Restoring 1 unacknowledged message(s)
```

This tells me the task is kept somewhere else other then the queue, but I cannot figure out where

Comment: For monitoring all upcoming and done tasks you can use `Flower` tool. https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Flower is another process..I want to be able to know if a task exists from inside the application and if not, resubmit the task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is actually the expected behavior as workers grab pending tasks even before execution to speed things up and thus remove them from queue.

To achieve what I wanted, which is disable workers from taking tasks from queues before actually starting to work on them, and losing track of that task,  I had to use 2 celery settings together

```
task_acks_late = True
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
```

This way a task is removed from its original queue, but still exists in a queue called 'unacked', which allows me to monitor it. [Optimizing celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html?highlight=prefetch)

Be advised that using the 'acks_late' [acks late](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-late-acknowledgment) setting has some side affects you need to be aware of, such that if a worker unexpectedly terminated, the task will be restored and re run next time the worker is revived.